# How do I make an error response for a specific command on a cog discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a kick command in a cog and it works. But the error event that I put for the kick command triggers all the other error events that I have set up in my other cogs. For example, I have a ban command (ban.py) and a kick command (kick.py). each have their own code for the error event like the code below. But I want them to have its own error like `@kick.error` or `@ban.error` because when I get an error on one of the commands, it shows the error for both of them. But sadly `@kick.error` or `@ban.error` doesn't work in cogs. Please help me fix this.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command _error(self, ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('(text here)')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("(text here)")
```

Comment: Use `elif` statements instead of `if` ones. Also if you want to have a specific error handler you have to use something like you mentioned (`@kick.error`)

Comment: The specific command handlers don't work in cogs though, when I tried to do `@kick.error` in the cog file it didn't work, but it works in the main file where my token is. @Dominik

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `Cog.cog_command_error` to make a local error handler for the cog:

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):  # no need for a decorator
        ...  # handle errors here
```

Comment: its not letting me run the code, sadly 
@Łukasz Kwieciński

Comment: I'm not, it just won't run.

Answer (score 0):

**Łukasz Kwieciński** version already makes sense, but here is a slightly modified one, maybe this one will help:

```py
class ErrorCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        try:
            if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
                pass
            elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
                # Do what you want to do.
            elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
                # Do what you want to do.
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"{error}")
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"{error}")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(ErrorCog(bot))
```

- We use the same event (`on_command_error`)
- We add the `class` to the `bot`

Comment: thank you sir for all the help, this one works.

Comment: but i get an error saying "isinstance expected 2 arguments, got 3" and now its doing the thing again triggering multiple error statements. @Łukasz Kwieciński

Comment: I have multiple commands in my cog that each have their errors showing up up the same time like unban, ban, kick, mute, unmute, clear, and other stuff.

Comment: @BrandonFigueroa Can you show us how one of the commands? This code should not trigger all of the errors if you use `elif` statements.

Comment: here is my ban.py file
https://pastebin.pl/view/709799f8
@Łukasz Kwieciński

Comment: Can you please set up a new `cog` with just the errors? I do not know if it will affect the commands if you do it in that way.

Comment: Oh sorry, I accidently thought you were the other guy. I'll try to set up a new cog. @Dominik

Comment: It still doesn't work sadly because I got an error that the error response needs to be in the same file as the command

Comment: @BrandonFigueroa This does not make any sense, then it is your code that is not working. I have never seen an error that tells you to have the `on_command_error` listener in the same file. This works fine for me in different `cogs` that were `setup`

Comment: I mean when i do `on_command_error` its triggering all of my errors. I only want it to trigger a certain command error. Like lets say I did `.kick` , my bot would trigger the errors for the other commands and be like, 
"`please say who you would like to ban,
please say who you would like to kick,
please say who you would like to mute`" all at the same time after i only do `.kick` 
@Dominik

Comment: @BrandonFigueroa Then build in „return” statements